# meta_query , why does not it work relation = or?

Tags: arrays, wordpress, relation

```
<?php
$param_1 = array( 'key' => 'width_picture', 'value' => array( $_GET['width_min'], $_GET['width_max'] ), 'compare' => 'BETWEEN');
$param_2 = array( 'key' => 'height_picture', 'value' => array( $_GET['height_min'], $_GET['height_max'] ), 'compare' => 'BETWEEN');
$param_3 = array( 'key' => '_price', 'value' => array( $_GET['price_min'], $_GET['price_max'] ), 'compare' => 'BETWEEN');

$massSort['relation']= 'OR';
$massSort[] = array($param_1, $param_2, $param_3);
var_dump($massSort);

$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'product', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' =>'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array($massSort)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

[More info](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query)

```
$meta_query = array('relation' => 'OR');

if (!empty($_GET['price_min']) && !empty($_GET['price_max'])):
    $meta_query[] = array(
        array(
            'key'       => '_price',
            'value'   => array( $_GET['price_min'], $_GET['price_max']  ),
            'type'    => 'numeric',
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        ),
    );
endif;

if (!empty($_GET['height_min']) && !empty($_GET['height_max'])):
$meta_query[] = array(
    array(
        'key'       => 'height_picture',
        'value'   => array( $_GET['height_min'], $_GET['height_max']),
        'type'    => 'numeric',
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
    ),
);
endif;

if (!empty($_GET['width_min']) && !empty($_GET['width_max'])):
$meta_query[] = array(
    array(
        'key'       => 'width_picture',
        'value'   => array(  $_GET['width_min'], $_GET['width_max'] ),
        'type'    => 'numeric',
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
    ),
);
endif;

$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'product', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' =>'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => meta_query
);
```

Comment: It is necessary that at least one parameter is sufficient for the output of the result

Comment: 'meta_query' => array('meta_query' => array(
             'relation' => 'OR',
              array(
           'key' => 'width_picture',
           'value' => array( $_GET['width_min'], $_GET['width_max'] ),
           'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
           'type'   => 'numeric'
           ),)  IT IS WORKING)!